# Is there an iPhone App that can trigger other Actions?

Tags: ios, iphone, triggers, action

I'm trying to see if anyone knows of an iPhone app that is capable of triggering custom actions based on other occurances that happen on your phone. I assume there's a jailbroken way to do this, but my phone isn't currently jailbroken (waiting for pangu soon hopefully).

Example:

I have an app that triggers an alert notification on my phone when there's motion sensed on my home security cameras via the Funlux app. It's great, but it's a very minor notification, and doesn't really get my attention, and is easily dismissed, etc. -- I want to have some way to say "When Funlux notifies me of X, do Y on my phone" (Like... make a more distinguished alert, or noise notification, or send me an email possibly, or beep again and again like an alarm until I disable it) - Some kind of custom action based on another action occurring in the OS.

Does that make sense?

The ultimate goal isn't really the interaction with the external device, that's just specific to this example. Really what I am looking for is an app that can essentially be 'listening' or 'waiting' for particular events on the iPhone to occur, then executing actions from that point. Another example could be "If a text message is received from person X, instantly reply with a message saying Y" or maybe "If my phone geo coordinates leave 200ft from my house's address, do X" --- Get what I'm going for?

Anyone have any direction? I've looked at Workflow, and that's all cool but definitely is not quite scriptable/customizable enough or really 'based on natural occurring events', but is more based on 'click this once to have 5 things happen in a workflow' which isn't really what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want the notifications to be triggered by an external device, you should look into use push notifications. That requires a remote server that interacts with Apples Push Notification Service (APNs).

A push notification targets a specific app, and can be made to launch your app in the background. Your app could then decide to trigger a local notification, including a sound.

Comment: The ultimate goal isn't really the interaction with the external device, that's just specific to this example. Really what I am looking for is an app that can essentially be 'listening' for particular events on the iPhone to occur, then executing actions from that point. Another example could be "If a text message is received from person X, instantly reply with a message saying Y" or maybe "If my phone geo coordinates leave 200ft from my house's address, do X" --- Get what I'm going for?